# Queue Task Scheduling

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have many command scheduling in kernel file. let's say all run **->daily()**, did they run one after one or run together. and if so, how can I let them run one after one?

Comment: you can simply add queue

Comment: how? or the source explaining the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel commands can start at the same time, even if other tasks still running. To change it use `withoutOverlapping()` method on your command like eg.

```
$schedule->command('command:start')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: this stop other commands from running until the current one end, or just prevent the same command from re-run?